# What does "period" mean when someone says "Sth... Period"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I often hear US citizens say something like this:

> <*Some phrases*>. ***Period***.

What does *period* mean when it appears in a sentence by itself in this type of situation?

Comment: In Britain they say "full stop" and not "period".  With the same meaning, as explained in the answers.

Comment: @GEdgar, Really? That's interesting... I never knew that.

Comment: @GEdgar: Many Brits now say *"End of"* in this context (i.e. - *"End of **story**", "No further discussion")*.

Comment: @GEdgar, I knew the period was called a full stop, but I don't think I've ever heard (or read) a sentence like (to borrow from Clark Kent), "Phones should only be used for communication, full stop." Is that what you meant? British people say that? (I wish I could find a video of that, but couldn't seem to.)

Comment: I guess *Black-Adder* is considered British?  So maybe there is a video of this scene somewhere: http://www.suslik.org/Humour/FilmOrTV/BlackAdder/ba2-6.html

Comment: it's strange that there is virtually no crossover between British and American with this particular word

Comment: I think there is. I can't imagine an American not understanding it.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/period#Interjection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Period* at the end of the sentence means, the things said in the sentence are definite and no change is allowed.

For example, "I want the document without any errors, period" meaning that there should not be any errors in the document.

Answer (score 20):

A period is what the full stop is called in American English. Saying *period* at the end of a sentence is a way of expressing the finality of what is being said. For example,

> A: But phones are good for taking pictures.
>
> B: No, I don't think so. Phones should only be used for communication,
>   **period**.

Comment: Moreover, your final word ***period*** there can be rewritten as ***full stop*** without any change in meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @tchrist: Except possibly confusing some American listeners.  "Full stop" tends to sound more like something from an old-timey telegram.  "NO I DONT THINK SO STOP TELEGRAPHS SHOULD ONLY BE USED FOR COMMUNICATION FULL STOP SIGNED NATE ELDREDGE"

Comment: @NateEldredge Are we really that confusable these days?

Comment: @tchrist & Nate, some of us are. :) I'd have at least given you the crooked head look for "full stop".

Answer (score 8):

In your example, *period* is used as an interjection. As the Wiktionary [explains](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/period):

> *Interjection*
>   1) (chiefly North America) And nothing else; and nothing less; used for emphasis.
>
> > When I say "eat your dinner," it means "eat your dinner," period!

You usually use it to end a sentence/statement/command which you don't want to discuss/negotiate further.