# When the word period is used after a sentence, what does it mean?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'period' mean when someone says “something, period”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/what-does-period-mean-when-someone-says-something-period)

When the word period is used after a sentence, like so:

> Bacon is awesome. Period.

What does it mean?