# What is the meaning of the word ' period' in the following context?

Tags: word-usage

I am learning English by reading the New York Times. It is difficult, of course, but a challenge at the same time. In the international edition it said:

The president is unfit for this crisis. Period.

In Spanish we would say: *al tiempo*. (*time* has the last word and all the answers, or *the passage of time*)

Who could help me?

Comment: "Period", in this context is a sort of exclamation.  It means that the statement is made and ends with a "." -- there is nothing further to discuss.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/period), sense 15 in the 'American English' section (though it is fairly common in the UK also; 'full stop' was/is used in this way too), the interjection usage. CED includes the definition, but gives a poorer definition.

Comment: I always assumed "period" here meant "full stop" (as in *That's the end of the sentence, and there won't be any more*). But now I discover from the full OED that it's a ***verb***, dating back to C16 - transitive *To bring to an end; to terminate* and intransitive *To come to a conclusion*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "period" mean when someone says "Sth... Period"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69662/what-does-period-mean-when-someone-says-sth-period)